# До 18 и после. О времени в разговорной речи

Tags: лексика

Если говорят "до 18-00", входит ли в этот временной промежуток 18-00 включительно? Или 18-00 входит в промежуток "после 18-00"? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В разговоре принимают участие как минимум две стороны, и надо требовать разъяснений у противной стороны о мере допустимой погрешности. Вопрос не корректный вообще и не уместный здесь, ибо проблем разговорной речи не касается никак. Если по письменности, то правильно указывать время следует так — 18:00.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не представляющего проблемы языка

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

Правило, о котором Вы говорите, нам неизвестно. Предлог до в одном из своих значений "употребляется при указании временного предела действия"; предлог по с винительным падежом в одном из значений "соответствует по значению предлогу до" (Словарь русского языка в 4 т. / Под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой). Для устранения неоднозначности рекомендуется использовать слово ***включительно***, когда нужно указать, что называемое число входит в состав промежутка: находиться в отпуске со второго по восьмое августа включительно (или: со второго до восьмого августа включительно). Предлоги до и по в указанном значении различаются, однако, по сочетаемости. Предлог по употребляется в устойчивых сочетаниях: по горло (сыт по горло), по пояс (стоять по пояс в воде). Предлог до употребляется в след. сочетаниях: до свидания, до ночи, до утра и т. п. Но чаще употребление вариативно: с августа по сентябрь и с (от) августа до сентября; раздеться по пояс и до пояса.

См.: [Непростые слова](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/hardwords?alpha=%D0%94)

Answer (score 1):

Формально есть три времени:

1) До 18:00;

2) 18:00;

3) После 18:00.

Сказали "до", значит, первый случай. 18:00 не относится ни к "до", ни к "после".

Answer (score 0):

Об этом наверняка знает только тот, кто говорит. Конечно, "после" - это после. А вот "во время" - это "до" или нет, остаётся только догадываться.

Для времени это неактуально, поскольку точное время - это миг нулевой протяженности. Никакое событие точно в ЧЧ:00 всё равно не происходит. 
Вот когда идет речь о датах о датах - типа "подать документы до 20 сентября" - вопрос становится интересным, можно ли подавать 20-го? Но русский язык на него однозначно не отвечает. Лучше оговорить это отдельно, например словом "включительно".

Подобные вопросы неоднократно обсуждались, если есть желание просто поищите поисковиком. Скорее всего найдёте аналогичный ответ.

//=====
Объясняю, что мне не нравится в ответе Сержа. Во-первых, он просто процитировал ответ на другой вопрос. Про **время** (а это существенно в вопросе) там нет ничего. В-вторых, цитирование сделано некорректно. Оторван сам вопрос. Это вводит читающего в заблуждение.

Comment: Вы цитируете ответ справки, да еще невнятно, приводите какие-то свои размытые объяснения. Минус - мой!

Comment: Я даю свои объяснения соответвующие вопросу. Свои. Когда я цитирую, я это делаю корректно. И почему это я не могу считать себя умнее Справки?

Comment: Во-первых, там отвечают филологи, а вы - не филолог. А во-вторых, и вашем сумбурном ответе  и в ответе справки ключевое слово " включительно". Так что же вам не понравилось в ответе справки? И в-третьих, я дал ссылку.

Comment: Я не собираюсь с Вами обсуждать, кто там отвечает. Я там был не раз, общался с людьми, а вы даже не знаете, кто там отвечает. Что  в ответе "справки" мне не понравилось - это опять же на обсуждению не выношу. Обсуждаемо только то, почему мне непонравился Ваш ответ, состоящий из цитаты, весьма косвенно относящийся к делу. И смените тон, пожалуйста, если хотите говорить. .

Comment: Я с вами общаюсь на вашем тоне.

Comment: *Я с вами общаюсь на вашем тоне*. - Ну и так смените его, если хотите разговоривать по существу.

Answer (score 0):

18:00 входит в промежуток между 18:00 и 18:01. Смайлик.
Когда просят прийти до шести, хотят, чтобы пришли в пять с чем-то, но не совсем близко к шести. Наверное, с шести уже что-то запланировано!
И наоборот: "встречаемся после шести" означает, что встречу хорошо бы начать не в 17:55, например, но и не в шесть, лучше даже пятью минутами позже, ну и так далее - в зависимости от того, есть ли крайний срок (вот в семь уже будет поздно). То есть человек скорее всего в шесть ровно еще немного занят или только-только сможет направляться на встречу.
Такие мысли исходят из подобного опыта.