# Предложение с предлогом "до"

Tags: лексика

Акция действует до 19. 07. 2017 00:59

Как понимать это предложение? Акция закончится в ночь с 18 на 19 или в ночь с 19 на 20?

Всегда считал правильным второй вариант, однако учредители акции считают правильным первый вариант.

Comment: Серж, Вы же ссылались на ответ Грамоты (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426849/%d0%94%d0%be-18-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%9e-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8/426850#426850)

Comment: МГ, я, конечно, читал свой ответ и помню о нем. Но меня интресует немного другое. 19 число начинается с 00:59 или заканчивается им? Сегодня утром акции уже не было. А когда я  обратился, к организатором, они ответили, что акция завршилась в ночь с 18 на 19.  На мой взгляд, на 00:59 день заканчивается, а не начинается.

Comment: Если бы была  указана просто дата, то вопроса бы и не возникло.

Comment: Не заметил, что там еще и часы и минуты указаны. Несомненно, 19. 07. 2017 00:59 - это 59 минут после полуночи в ночь с 18-го на 19-е (19-е уже наступило)

Comment: А разве 19 не должно наступить в 1:00 ночи?

Comment: Традиционно, сутки разделяются на 24 часа, отсчитываемых от **полуночи** (нашел в википедии). А календарная дата привязана к суткам. Все, кому приходилось ездить поездом или летать самолетом, знают это. Всем понятно, что значит "вылет в 00:59 19.07.2017"

Comment: Спасибо! Значит - организаторы правы.

Comment: ВЫ пишете "Всегда считал правильным первый вариант" .т.е ночь с 18 на 19. Это и есть правильный ответ

Comment: Ой, простите, хотел написать: в ночь  19 на 20.

Comment: Все исправил уже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

СУТКИ, -ток, -ткам; мн. Промежуток времени от одной **полуночи** до другой (Большой толковый словарь)

Традиционно, сутки разделяются на 24 часа, отсчитываемых от **полуночи** (Википедия).

А календарная дата привязана к суткам. Таким образом, **00:59 19.07.2017 наступает в ночь с 18-го на 19-е.**

Все, кому приходилось ездить поездом или летать самолетом, знают, что если  вылет назначен на 00:59 19.07.2017, то он состоится в ночь с 18-го на 19-е, а не с 19-го на 20-е.